# Why import a whole module then rename one of its functions?

Tags: python, import, flask, package

In [Flask](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask)'s top-level `__init__.py`, the following is done:

```
from . import json
jsonify = json.jsonify
```

1. Why not `import json`?
2. Why rename `json.jsonify`? Why not (i) `import json` then call `json.jsonify()` where needed or (ii) `from json import jsonify`, then call `jsonify()` where needed?

I know there are two comments, but they enlighten me little:

```
# We're not exposing the actual json module but a convenient wrapper around
# it.
from . import json

# This was the only thing that flask used to export at one point and it had
# a more generic name.
jsonify = json.jsonify
```

Comment: Seems like that should be written as `from .json import jsonify`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Why not `import json`?

Because that would import the `json` module from the standard library, and the authors want to import their own `json` module.

> 2. Why rename `json.jsonify`?

To make it slightly easier to write and read. Imagine you're using `flask`: `flask.jsonify()` is faster to write and more readable than `flask.json.jsonify()` (or, alternatively, it is easier to import, and does not give you a feeling that you are importing something from the deep guts of the library).

> Why not (i) `import json` then call `json.jsonify()` where needed

Remember that this file specifies *exports*. You would have to call it as `flask.json.jsonify()`.

> or (ii) `from json import jsonify`, then call `jsonify()` where needed?

Yes, the second line could have been written as

```
 from .json import jsonify
```

(as **mgilson** correctly noted). It's a matter of personal style, I guess.

Comment: Well ... It is slightly different.  `from .json import jsonify` wouldn't make `flask.json` available.  From the comments, it looks like they _don't_ want to make that available, but sometimes comments lie. . .

Comment: @mgilson: yes, that's why I said that the second line could have been written differently. My understanding of the cited comment was that by "actual json module" they'd meant the standard library one.

Comment: Ahh -- Yes, that would explain why they wrote it the way they did instead of `from .json import jsonify`